# What is the capacity of Earth? Is the Earth stable?

Tags: queueing-theory

I'm learning queueing theory and just finished [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law) and Utilization.

If the Earth is interpreted as a system that provides a service for its customers, is it unstable? Let the customers be the humans and let the service be ***sustaining life of said humans***.

Let $\lambda =$ Long-term Average Arrival of Customers

The long-term average arrival of customers (humans) into the system (planet Earth) is the global annual birth-rate.

Currently, the global average birth rate per 1,000 total population is 19.15 births in 2012. For the absolute global average birth rate is $\ 19.15 \cdot 7\times10^6 = 1.34 \times 10^8 \frac{\text{humans}}{\text{year}}$.

(World population in 2012 is $7$ billion $ = 7 \times 10^9 $)

Let $\ \bar x = $Average Time in System a.k.a. Average Life-Expectancy of Human.

Current average life-expectancy (regardless of sex) is$\ 71 \frac{\text{years of service}}{\text{human}}$.

$$\lambda \cdot \bar x = 9.54\times10^9 $$

Let $\ C$ be the capacity of humans Earth can have. What is $\ C$? If $\ C < 9.54\times10^9 $ then Earth, as a system, is unstable. Is $\ C $ the death rate?

P.S.: The utilization factor is $\rho = \dfrac{\lambda \cdot \bar x}{C} $

Comment: Before anyone starts thinking of anything in this as somewhat realistic, let us recall that both human life expectancy and the ability of the Earth to support a specified number of humans is constantly changing with changes in technology and economic circumstances. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Queueing theory will give you a metric in steady-state only. As conditions of life and resources are time-varying, as pointed by @MichaelHardy, such model is not useful. A differential (difference) equation will more suitable type of model. (just for fun: see [Logistic Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) for a reference)